# Defining setup, teardown and variable in argumentfile in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Basically 2 issues:

**1.** I plan to execute multiple test cases from argument file. The structure would look like that:

```
SOME_PATH/  
-test_cases/  
-some_keywords/  
-argumentfile.txt
```

How should i define a suite setup and teardown for all those test cases executed from file (-A file)?

From what i know:
a) I could execute it in file with 1st and last test case, but the order of test cases may change so it is not desired.

b) provide it in **init**.robot and put it somewhere without test cases only to get the setup and teardown. This is because if I execute:

```
robot -i SOME_TAG -A argumentfile  /path/to/init
```

and the init is in test_case folder it will execute  the test_cases with a specific tag + those in a folder twice.

Is there any better way? Provide it, for example, in argumentfile?

**2** How to provide PATH variable in argumentfiles in robotframework?
I know there is possibility to do:
--variable PATH:some/path/to/files

but is it not for test suite env?

How to get that variable to be visible in the file itself: ${PATH}/test_case_1.robot

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd question, you could create a temporary environment variable that you'd then use. Depending on the OS you're using, the way you'll do this will be different:

Windows:

```
set TESTS_PATH=some/path/here
robot -t %TESTS_PATH%/test_case_1.robot
```

Unix:

```
export TESTS_PATH="some/path/here"
robot -t $TESTS_PATH/test_case_1.robot
```

*PS: you might want to avoid asking multiple, different questions in the same thread*